# Asciidoctor "Snippets" is missing in Maven

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, asciidoc, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

When I run the test case then requests and responses of adoc type will be created and displayed in JSON format under the generated-snippets directory. when I run this mvn command `mvn clean package` to create jar and HTML type of index under the generated-docs then following warning has occurred

[image]

when I open the index.html via browser then `Unresolved directive in index.adoc` is displayed instead of JSON result as a response.

[image]

*pom.xml*

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

     
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>config-demo</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>product</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

*index.adoc*

```
= Nafaz Benzema Getting Started With Spring REST Docs

    This is an example output for a service running at http://localhost:9090:
    
==GET API Example

.request
include::{snippets}/getAllProduct/http-request.adoc[]

.response
include::{snippets}/getAllProduct/http-response.adoc[]

As you can see the format is very simple, and in fact you always get the same message.
```

*Controller Test class*

```
@ExtendWith({RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class})
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(outputDir = "/target/generated-snippets")
public class ProductControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;


    @MockBean
    private ProductService productService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    List<Product> products =null;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext, RestDocumentationContextProvider documentationContextProvider) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration(documentationContextProvider))
                .build();

        products=getProducts();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllProduct() throws Exception {

        String expectedProduct=new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(products);

        Mockito.when(productService.getAllProduct()).thenReturn(products);

        MvcResult result= mockMvc.perform(get("/products")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json(expectedProduct))
                .andDo(document("{methodName}",preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                        preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())))
                .andReturn();

        String actualProduct=result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedProduct,actualProduct);

    }

    private List<Product> getProducts()
    {
        Product product_1=new Product();
        product_1.setProductId(1001);
        product_1.setProductName("Penguin-ears");
        product_1.setNumberOfUnitInCartoon(20);
        product_1.setPriceOfCartoon(175.00);
        product_1.setUrlOfImage("https://i.ibb.co/pLdM7FL/shutterstock-306427430-scaled.jpg");

        Product product_2=new Product();
        product_2.setProductId(1002);
        product_2.setProductName("Horseshoe");
        product_2.setNumberOfUnitInCartoon(5);
        product_2.setPriceOfCartoon(825);
        product_2.setUrlOfImage("https://i.ibb.co/MRDwnqj/horseshoe.jpg");

        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(product_1,product_2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found. We have to add `spring-restdocs-asciidoctor` dependency inside the plugin which it belongs.

Remove `spring-restdocs-asciidoctor` dependency from the global dependency management space and add it inside the plugin

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>product</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```